# Akka/Java getContext().become with parameter?

Tags: java, scala, akka

In Akka/Scala one is able to pass parameters to the custom receive function, so it is possible to pass the whole actor state through params, without using mutable variables.

```
context.become(myCustomReceive(param1, param2))
```

But in Java Api you can pass only Procedure which gets the received message as the only param

```
getContext().become( new Procedure<Object> {
  public void apply(Object param) throws Exception
  {
    // ... 
  }
}
```

Is there a clean way to do the same trick in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this

```
class ProcedureWithParams<T> extends Procedure<T> {
   Object param1;
   Object param2;

   ProcedureWithParams(Object param1, Object param2) {
      this.param1 = param1;
      this.param2 = param2;
   }

   public void apply(Object param) throws Exception {
    //access para1 and param2 here
   }

}

getContext().become( new ProcedureWithParams(param1, param2))
```